# Extract part of file and print using python

Tags: python

I want to extract part of the file content . Which starts with ("head"
and ends with ("arraydat"

content of file:

```
(record
  ( "head"
    (record
     ( "pname" "C16D")
     ( "ptype" "probe")
       ( "sn" "11224")
         ( "rev" "1")
          ( "opname" "Kaji")
         ( "comm"
         [ "" ]
        )
      ( "numel" 192)
      ( "mux" 1)
      ( "freq" 3400000)
     ( "date" 63602497416.093)
      ( "focus" 0.066)
      ( "probID" 574)
          ( "te" 0)
     ( "therm" 0)
      ( "bipolar" "N/A")
      ( "maker" "YMS")
     ( "PartNum" 5418916)
       ( "numrow" 1)
       )
      )
     ( "arraydat"
       (record
      ( "FL6" 1625283.947393933)
      ( "FH6" 4932875.254089763)
     ( "FL20" 1283607.261269079)
     ( "FH20" 5673248.882271254)
     ( "Fc" 3279079.600741847)
      ( "BW" 100.8695033187829)
      ( "PW6" 3.316821935120381E-007)
    ( "PW20" 9.740000000000003E-007)
       ( "PW30" 1.456E-006)
       ( "PW40" 2.628000000000001E-006)
       ( "LG" -46.35823409318354)
       ( "TOF" -1.363659434369523E-008)
        )
```

I need to extract the content of a file after "head" and before "arraydat". 
 I have tried this command but no luck

```
import re
    with open('sample.txt','r') as new_file:
    data = new_file.read()
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s[(]\s"head"[\s\S]*?\s[(]\s"arraydat"')
    stringtext = re.findall(pattern, data)
    print(stringtext)
```

Output should look like this:

```
    ( "pname" "C16D")
  ( "ptype" "probe")
     ( "sn" "11224")
    ( "rev" "1")
   ( "opname" "Kaji")
      ( "comm"
         [ "" ]
        )
      ( "numel" 192)
      ( "mux" 1)
      ( "freq" 3400000)
     ( "date" 63602497416.093)
      ( "focus" 0.066)
      ( "probID" 574)
          ( "te" 0)
     ( "therm" 0)
      ( "bipolar" "N/A")
      ( "maker" "YMS")
     ( "PartNum" 5418916)
       ( "numrow" 1)
       )
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = []
read = False

for line in open('test.dat'):
    if line.strip() == '( "head"':
        read = True
        continue
    elif line.strip() == '( "arraydat"':
        read = False
    if read:
        data.append(line.rstrip())

print('\n'.join(data))
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. it works great. Can you help me with the code where first  part of the line is header of csv file and second part as data. For Example if  ( "pname" "C16D") is the content, i would like to put "pname" as header of csv file and "C16D" as data below that header, similar process for rest of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code:

```
import re
import csv

data_list= []
record_data = False
comm_line = False

#Open file read data.
#Save one set of data between 'head' and 'arraydat' in single dict
#Append that dict to data list

with open('sample.txt','r') as new_file:
     for line in new_file:
          if '( "head"' in line:
              record_data  = True
              data_dict = {}
              continue

          if '( "arraydat"' in line:
              data_list.append(data_dict)
              record_data = False

          #Data from comm line  
          if "comm" in line and record_data:
              comm_line = True
              nline = ''

          if comm_line:
              n = re.match(r'\s*\)\s*$',line)
              if n is not None:
                comm_line=False
                nline = nline + line.strip('\r\n')
                line=re.sub(' +',' ',nline)
                n = None
              else:
                nline = nline + line.strip('\r\n')
                next

          if record_data:
             line  = line.strip()
             if line.startswith('(') and line.endswith(')'):
                  line = line.strip(')(').strip()
                  #line = re.sub('\"',"",line)
                  #print line
                  m = re.match(r'\"(\w+)\"\s+\"*([\w+\W+]+)\"*',line)
                  if m is not None:
                       k = m.group(1).strip('"')
                       v  = m.group(2).strip('"')
                       data_dict[k]=v

print data_list

#Write it to csv
with open('output.csv','wb') as out_file:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=data_list[0].keys())
     writer.writeheader()
     for data in data_list:
          writer.writerow(data)
```

**Output :**

*On console:*

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python b.py
[{'therm': '0', 'probID': '574', 'PartNum': '5418916', 'numrow': '1', 'rev': '1'
, 'ptype': 'probe', 'mux': '1', 'bipolar': 'N/A', 'maker': 'YMS', 'comm': '[ ""
]', 'sn': '11224', 'numel': '192', 'focus': '0.066', 'date': '63602497416.093',
'pname': 'C16D', 'opname': 'Kaji', 'te': '0', 'freq': '3400000'}, {'therm': '0',
 'probID': '574', 'PartNum': '5418916', 'numrow': '1', 'rev': '1', 'ptype': 'pro
be', 'mux': '1', 'bipolar': 'N/A', 'maker': 'YMS', 'comm': '[ "" ]', 'sn': '1122
4', 'numel': '192', 'focus': '0.066', 'date': '63602497416.093', 'pname': 'C16D'
, 'opname': 'Dinesh', 'te': '0', 'freq': '3400000'}]

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

*Content of **output.csv**:*

```
therm,probID,PartNum,numrow,rev,ptype,mux,bipolar,maker,comm,sn,numel,focus,date,pname,opname,te,freq
0,574,5418916,1,1,probe,1,N/A,YMS,"[ """" ]",11224,192,0.066,63602497416.093,C16D,Kaji,0,3400000
0,574,5418916,1,1,probe,1,N/A,YMS,"[ """" ]",11224,192,0.066,63602497416.093,C16D,Dinesh,0,3400000
```

Comment: Thanks. I am also looking to put this content into csv file . Where  first part goes as header and second part goes as data underneath it. For Example if ( "pname" "C16D") is the content, i would like to put "pname" as header of csv file and "C16D" as data below that header, similar process for rest of the lines. I think you know whats my expected output :)

Comment: No, thats not working. Can i get a optimised solution.

Comment: only header part is appearing in the output file .csv but the data is not coming into the csv

Comment: Dinesh I am getting this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dinesh.py", line 60, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join(wrong_fields))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: numrow, numel, date, ptype,
comm, mux, PartNum, maker, rev, opname, focus, probID, pname, bipolar, sn, freq,
 te, therm

Comment: Also data_list[0].keys() is displaying only MWK
YMS
pallet
probe
TMX
VND

Comment: @HarshithaGoli  - Data parser I have written works perfectly with the data you have shared in question. But it seems to be broken when you are running complete file which you have. Can you share your data file somewhere - Google Drive or DropBox and share link ?

Comment: Hello Dinesh. Check the file here: I have lot of fields to extract in similar way , the one i posted in this question is one part. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3sGGXGj99rubzBZTnlRN1N2OGdvSnlSWVNzckZ3cE9UWEZ3/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I figured out the issue. head part is repeating twice hence the data got jumbled. Modified the code and it works fine now :)

Comment: @HarshithaGoli  - Addressed the issue.Not only head but arraydat is also reapeating twice. :) Please accept it as answer now :)

Comment: Can you help me to extract arraydat part. I am facing issue in matching the string  m = re.match(r'\"(\w+)\"\s+*([\w+\W+]+)*',line) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    with open('sample.txt', 'r') as fileObject:
        fileData = fileObject.read().split("\n")

    fileDataClean = [data.strip() for data in fileData]

    startIndex, stopIndex = fileDataClean.index('( "head"'), fileDataClean.index('( "arraydat"')
    resultData = "\n"join(fileData[startIndex:stopIndex])
    print(resultData)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

***I hope this helps.***